# VB.NET For loop adding extra character

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, for-loop, character

I don't really know how to explain the error...
CODE:

```
Public Class AnagramSolver
    Private inputChars() As Char
    Private Sub btnSolveAnagram_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSolveAnagram.Click
        If Not input.Text.Length <= 1 Then
            ReDim inputChars(input.Text.Length - 1)
            For i = 1 To input.Text.Length 'puts each character from string into an array
                inputChars(i - 1) = Mid(input.Text, i, 1)
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("The length of the anagram must be at least 2")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I use a For Next loop to step through a string and put each character into an array. But when i'm debugging with the watch window, an extra character is in every element of the array.
These are the array elements in the watch window.
inputted string = "james"

```
(0) = "j"c
(1) = "a"c
(2) = "m"c
(3) = "e"c
(4) = "s"c
```

I have no idea where the extra 'c' is coming from. any help?

Comment: you do not need that loop.  `Dim inputChars = input.Text.ToCharArray` should work as long as the right side is a string.

Comment: btw did you mean the left side needs to be a string?

Comment: no, the right side or `input.Text`  a string is basically a CharArray (which is what VS is showing you with `c`).  With option Infer, VB will make `inputChars` a char array based on what the right side is/returns.

Comment: more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24398217/1070452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These 'c's aren't a part of the value, it's simply the debugger's represantation of a `char`.

It prints them out so you know that it's a `char "j"`, not a `string "j"`. As such, it has no effect to how your code works.

Comment: ahhh, thanks :) I knew it would be something simple like that

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as the solution! Thanks

Comment: I forgot haha, i tried earlier but it was too 'early'